# Gardle sync error due to dependency being unresolvable

Tags: android-studio, build, dependencies

I am currently developing an android app with AR features using the library `com.gorisse.thomas.sceneform:sceneform:1.21.0`. It was working fine up until now. Whenever I try to sync the project the dependency is not resolvable.

I once had this exact same problem, but a simple computer restart resolved the issue. Now that doesn't work anymore. I tried deleting the `.idea` and `.gradle` folders and importing the project instead of opening it.

More details:

The error I get:

```
Failed to resolve: com.gorisse.thomas.sceneform:sceneform:1.21.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

What my build.gradle looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
        pickFirsts += ['META-INF/DEPENDENCIES']
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rocksterapp"
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    androidResources {
        noCompress 'filamat', 'ktx'
    }
    namespace 'com.example.<appname>'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.filament:filamat-android:1.21.1'
    implementation 'com.gorisse.thomas.sceneform:sceneform:1.21.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Edit:

I created a new project and just simply copied every file from the old one into it. Problem isn't fixed. Now not only one dependency can't be resolved but three. Sceneform is not included in these.

Comment: Maybe a very simple solution, but try it again on a different day? I'm using the same dependency of SceneForm in my Project and I have no issues. SceneForm is distributed through Maven Central, maybe the service was offline or had issues. Next time checkout https://status.maven.org/

Comment: Managed to fix it by simply creating a new Project and copying every file over (not changing anything in the process).